# Migrating MySQL DB instance on RDS to Amazon Aurora

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I had created a MySQL DB instance on RDS, following are the details:

Instance class - db.t2.micro
Engine version - 8.0.17
It is present in us-east-1 region.

Now I have to move my MySQL DB to Amazon Aurora, following were the documentation guides which i followed:
1- https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Migrating.RDSMySQL.Replica.html

On following the above guide i am only able to create a read replica. The option for creating a aurora replica is not visible. Also, when i create read replica it is created for mysql db and not gives me option to create for any other engine type.

2- https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Migrating.RDSMySQL.Import.html

On following the above guide, i am able to create snapshot for my mysql db instance. But, the option to 'Migrate Snapshot' is disabled. Could anyone please help me with this.

Could anyone also suggest me any other way in which i can migrate my MySQL db on RDS to Amazon Aurora?

Answer (score 0):

Aurora MySQL is only supported for MySQL 5.6 and 5.7 unfortunately so the read replica solution would not work.

However, Amazon have you covered with the [Database Migration Service](https://aws.amazon.com/dms/).

AWS published a [blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/migrating-from-mysql-to-amazon-aurora-using-aws-sct-and-aws-dms/) on this, so take a read.